# Synthetic Control when leaving treatment

Tags: synthetic-data

I'm trying to do a comparative analysis using synthetic control to compare a country that went from a dictatorship to democracy to it's dictatorial synthetic twin.

As I understand it, synthetic control has been used for some of this issues, but only when the dictatorship began. Is it appropriate to build the synthetic dictatorial twin with democratic or non-dictatorial countries to estimate the effect of entering democracy?

Would it be appropriate to try to estimate the synthetic control group back in time, using data from when the treatment ended to today, and then letting the synthetic twin go back in time to compare the control with the actual country before the treatment? (say, if the synthetic control would need to start from a lower level to reach today's levels, this would be evidence in favour of the dictatorship having some negative impact)

Answer (score 0):

1. guess country-level comparison is already quite hard to draw a valid conclusion, really depends on what your outcome variable is, which metric you want to compare?
2. if i understand correct, synthetic control group is used to form a control group that the treatment/intervention (in this case - democracy) is not happening, hoping to demo the counterfactual situation (what would have happened in absence of democracy), so why would you include 'already-democratic-countries' in your synthetic group? if so, i guess the question you want to answer will be changing.
3. actually i thought about the same thing, why not just compare to itself in different times? look at year-over-year metrics? check if there's level-shifting. but note that of course the different may be attributed to a lot of other time-(in)variant factors rather than the mere intervention of 'democracy'